# Submit form not connected to multiple fields

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form on a webpage that I want a user to be able to fill out, hit submit, and it displays something like "User: [name] has a [event] event at [location] with details [description]" in a comment section below. So multiple entries will just load under each other. Right now when I hit submit, it will only submit the description text and nothing else. My function  getInfo() should be displaying multiple values but is not. How can I remedy this. Full code linked below

https://github.com/tayrembos/Nav/blob/master/back.html

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
                function getInfo() {
                  text = name.value;
                  text = words.value;
                  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML += '<p>'+ text
                  document.getElementById("words").value = "Enter comment"
                  document.getElementById('name').value = "Enter name"
                }
              </script>

              <form method="POST" name='myform'>
                <p>Enter your name:
                  <textarea id='name' rows="1" cols="20">Enter name</textarea>

               <textarea id='name' rows="1" cols="20">Enter name</textarea>

                <textarea id='words' rows="10" cols="20">Enter comment</textarea>
                <input type="button" onclick="getInfo()" value="Submit!" /> <br>
                <p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use append from jquery(vote if it really solves your problem).

```js
function myFunction() {

  var x = document.getElementById("product");  
  var txt = "";
  var all = {};
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i<x.length-1; i++) {

          //txt = txt + x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
          all[x.elements[i].name]= x.elements[i].value;

  }

$("p").append(JSON.stringify(all, null, 2));

    //var myObj = { "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" };

     //document.getElementById("demothree").innerHTML = myObj;

    //var myJSON = JSON.stringify(all);
    //window.location = "server.php?x=" + myJSON;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="product">
  
  Expire: <input type="text" name="pexpire" value="3:45"><br>
  Old Price: <input type="text" name="poldprice" value="30"><br>
  Price: <input type="text" name="pprice" value="28"><br>
  Category: <input type="text" name="pcategory" value="Ενδύματα"><br>
  Variaty: <input type="text" name="pvariaty" value="Τζιν"><br>
  City: <input type="text" name="pcity" value="Δράμα"><br>
  Store: <input type="text" name="pstore" value="Groove"><br>
  Picture: <input type="text" name="ppicture" value="aaa"><br>

  

</form> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<p id="list"></p>
```